# How to display only 3 items from my backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I`m new in backbone and I`m stuck with this issue. I need to display 3 items for my collection and the after clicking show more display another 3 of them. 
I know I can use for example `first()` method for `underscore.js` but how ?
Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
var Tasks = Backbone.Model.extend();
var TasksList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Tasks,
    url: 'json/data.json'
}); 


var TasksView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#tasks",
    template: _.template($('#taskTemplate').html()),
    render: function() {
        _.each(this.model.models, function(tasks){
            var taskTemplate = this.template(tasks.toJSON());
            $(this.el).append(taskTemplate);
        }, this);

        return this;
    }
});

var tasks = new TasksList();    
var tasksView = new TasksView({model: tasks});
tasks.fetch({reset:true});
tasks.bind('reset', function () {
    tasksView.render();
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use underscores `first` method. Hope this helps

```
var TasksView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#tasks',

    template: _.template($('#taskTemplate').html()),

    initialize: function () {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    },

    render: function () {
        _.each(this.collection.first(3), function (task) {
            var html = this.template(task.toJSON());

            this.$el.append(html);
        }, this);

        return this;
    }
}

var tasks = new TasksList(),   
    tasksView = new TasksView({ collection: tasks });

tasks.fetch({ reset:true });
```

Comment: I works thanks a lot but how to for example load 3 more tasks after clicking button show more ?

Comment: this.collection.rest(index) will return the values of the array from that index onward.

Comment: Hmm I new in backbone and I'm really sorry but dont know how to us it to load another 3 elements. Here is a question what I really want to achieve.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755017/load-more-data-button-backbone

Comment: If your problem is solved, mark a question as closed, thus you will help other newbies ;)